# Cmake generator expression command

Tags: cmake

If some boolean condition is true (such as ENABLE_TESTING) then I want to run something like:

```
COMMAND ./b2 --with-filesystem --with-program_options --with-test
```

And if the boolean condition is false, then I instead want:

```
COMMAND ""
```

It seems like I can achieve that with this very ugly code:

```
COMMAND $<$<BOOL:${ENABLE_TESTING}>:./b2> $<$<BOOL:${ENABLE_TESTING}>:--with-filesystem> $<$<BOOL:${ENABLE_TESTING}>:--with-program_options> $<$<BOOL:${ENABLE_TESTING}>:--with-test>
```

But as you can see, I have to repeat the boolean test over and over. If I naively try to combine them into a single expression:

```
COMMAND $<$<BOOL:${ENABLE_TESTING}>:./b2 --with-filesystem --with-program_options --with-test>
```

Then I get the error `/bin/sh: 1: $<1:./b2: not found`. The spaces, apparently, get parsed before the generator expression is evaluated. So I quote the whole thing:

```
COMMAND "$<$<BOOL:${ENABLE_TESTING}>:./b2 --with-filesystem --with-program_options --with-test>"
```

But this produces the error `/bin/sh 1: /b2 --with-filesystem --with-program_options --with-test: not found`. I suppose it's treating the whole thing as the name of a command rather than a command with options. How can I write this in a way that is clean and works?

EDIT: I've tried to simplify the code for a minimum example, but there's an extra complication I left out. This command is happening in an `ExternalProject_Add` section, and I need to rely on special tokens such as `<BINARY_DIR>`.

```
COMMAND ./b2 "--stagedir=<BINARY_DIR>" --with-filesystem --with-program_options --with-test
```

I can't move the commands into an if statement elsewhere, because if I do then the directory tokens aren't expanded.

Comment: I don't get it, can you please post a minimal example?

Comment: ? `if (ENABLE_TESTING) set(args "./b2 --with-filesystem --with-program_options --with-test") else() set(args "\"\"") endif() execute_command(COMMAND "${args}")` ??? Och I get it. What if you `COMMAND /bin/sh -c "[ -n \"$<${ENABLE_TESTING}>:x>\" ] && ./b2 --with-filesystem --with-program_options --with-test; " ` ?

Comment: @KamilCuk I added an edit explaining why the first doesn't work. And the second is platform-specific, which defeats the purpose of cmake.

Answer (score 2):

Code readability-wise, generator expressions are an unfortunate addition to the CMake language. In scenarios like yours where generator expression cannot be avoided, I use a regular CMake variable to avoid code duplication, i.e.:

```
set (_runB2GenEx "$<BOOL:${ENABLE_TESTING}>")
ExternalProject_Add(example
    ...
    COMMAND 
        $<${_runB2GenEx}:./b2> 
        $<${_runB2GenEx}:--stagedir=<BINARY_DIR>> 
        $<${_runB2GenEx}:--with-filesystem> 
        $<${_runB2GenEx}:--with-program_options> 
        $<${_runB2GenEx}:--with-test>
    ...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the help of `COMMAND_EXPAND_LISTS`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)
set(ENABLE_TESTING 1)
add_custom_target(
  foo COMMAND "$<$<BOOL:${ENABLE_TESTING}>:./b2;--with-filesystem;--with-program_options;--with-test>"
  COMMAND_EXPAND_LISTS)
```

Let's check that it works:

```
$ cmake .
$ VERBOSE=1 make foo
...
./b2 --with-filesystem --with-program_options --with-test
Built target foo
```

Comment: One of the caveats is that the command can't be set in a variable ahead of time (so far as I can tell), because otherwise special ExternalProject tokens such as `<BINARY_DIR>` won't be evaluated.

Comment: @JeffM It works without the variable too. I updated the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. `<BINARY_DIR>` doesn't work outside the context of an `ExternalProject_Add` command, which means a custom target wouldn't expand it either.